# Anyone know the purpose of these two inductors around a metallic ring?

Tags: power, transformer, inductor

So this link on ebay shows a power board that I have taken out from my microwave.

What is the purpose of these two wrapped around a metal ring? Also in general what is the purpose of this power board it takes in an input voltage of 120V AC but what does it output?

[image]

[image]

The circuit diagram shows the inductors without the toroid. The inductance is incorrect, I am not sure that the Henry value would be for them.

Comment: the "metal" ring is a ferrite toroid.  It only looks metallic because of the coating, although it may contain metals in it's composition.

Comment: thanks for editing, but the symbol for a common mode choke shows magnetic linkage between the two coils.  It really is a transformer that is optimized for this use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <strike>At the top left, the tan (with color bands) resistor and yellow capacitor form a RC-snubber network. This mainly filters spikes due to instantaneously switching off an inductive load (main transformer);</strike>
- According to your diagram R1 and C1 are in parallel, then it is not an RC-snubber like I expected. R1 is there to discharge the capacitors after disconnecting the device from mains power, so you won't get zapped when you touch the leads when you unplug the device from the wall socket.
- Top middle thing with the two coper wires is a common mode choke. It is a bit difficult to explain how it works, so I'll leave it to the others to answer that. Until then here is an article on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choke_%28electronics%29#Common-mode_choke);
- The blue things, capacitors to Ground. Together with the common mode choke they form a filter to ground for high frequency noise.;
- You probably recognized the fuse at the bottom left.

Apart from the fuse all these subcircuits form a filter with specific goal. The overall goal is to prevent the microwave from emitting electric noise onto the power lines and cause other devices (eg. your radio or TV) to malfunction. At the same time prevent power line noise from other devices to disrupt the microwave from properly functioning.

Comment: That's a very good explanation however I don't understand how capacitors to ground would filter our high frequency noise could you explain that a little more?

Comment: Why not raise that as a separate question, or search the site to see if it has already been asked.

Answer (score 3):

The board does two things.  It protects the microwave from shorts, electrical noise, and line faults such as voltage spikes.  It also protects the line from noise the microwave generates.

The wires wrapped around the metal toroid form an inductor.  This is to prevent electrical noise the microwave generates transferring to the powerline, and electrical noise on the powerline from transferring to the microwave.  It's done primarily in order to meet emissions requirements (in the US the FCC regulates this), but also to prevent line noise from affecting microwave operation.

You can read more about noise suppression ferrites here:

http://audiosystemsgroup.com/SAC0305Ferrites.pdf

Comment: so is the output still 120V AC but filtered?

Comment: @user1084113 Without seeing the other side I can't be certain, but it's very likely.  The blue items on the right are likely MOVs to absorb voltage spikes, the yellow item on the left is likely a capacitor (part of the filtering) with a resistor across it so it doesn't keep charge forever.  The fuse should be obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely this is an EMI filter.

C1 is between line and neutral and is what's referred to as an X-capacitor. Its purpose is to suppress differential-mode noise between line and neutral by showing a low impedance to high frequencies (usually in the high kilohertz to low megahertz range). Because this cap is across line and neutral, it will have its own safety mark on it somewhere.

The toroidal inductor is a common-mode choke. The starts and finishes are on the same 'side' of the circuit. It provides a high impedance to common-mode noise (line to earth, neutral to earth) and doesn't affect the normal current drawn by the device (which is differential by nature). The construction of the choke (two bunched windings spread apart) gives you some leakage inductance, which is a high impedance to differential mode noise.

The other two caps are Y-capacitors, which provide a low impedance path for high frequency common-mode noise (line to earth, neutral to earth) and will also have their own safety marks.

From the perspective of EMI, you have two LC filters here:

- the CM choke and the Y-caps (common mode filter)
- the leakage inductance of the CM choke and the X-cap (differential filter)

The fuse is to isolate the unit from the mains in the event of a catastrophic circuit or isolation failure.